# .NET SSL error on Windows 7 only (ok on WIndows 10)

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssl

I tried to call the Dailymotion API using http request.
Problem: it works perfectly on Windows 10 but it fails on Windows 7. The error message is "The SSL connection could not be established. See inner exception."

Here's my code:

```
Dim strDailymotionApiRequest As String
Dim strDailymotionUser As String = "CanalplusSport"
Dim webDailymotionHandler As HttpClientHandler = New HttpClientHandler() With {
                                                            .Proxy = wpyProxy,
                                                            .UseProxy = True,
                                                            .ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator}
Dim htcDailmotion As HttpClient = New HttpClient(webDailymotionHandler)
Dim strDailymotionApiResponse As String
Dim jsonDailymotionApiResponse As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
        
strDailymotionApiRequest = "https://api.dailymotion.com/user/" & strDailymotionUser & "?fields=id,username,screenname,description,followers_total,views_total,videos_total,created_time,avatar_720_url"

Dim webDailymotionRequest As New HttpRequestMessage(Http.HttpMethod.Get, strDailymotionApiRequest)
Dim webDailymotionResponse As HttpResponseMessage = htcDailmotion.Send(webDailymotionRequest)
webDailymotionResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

Dim webDailymotionreader As New StreamReader(webDailymotionResponse.Content.ReadAsStream())
strDailymotionApiResponse = webDailymotionreader.ReadToEnd()
```

I tried to search an explanation here and there but can't find any one.

Comment: What was the content of the inner exception? It's likely that Windows 7 doesn't support an appropriate version of TLS. TLS 1.1 and 1.2 are not supported by default and TLS 1.3 is not supported at all.

Comment: Most likely because the code is using a default TLS version that is considered deprecated, either TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1. You probably need to set the default to 1.2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client. Notice that you need to do it manually, mainly because Windows 7 is out of support

Comment: Have you followed all the instructions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392) to enable TLS 1.2 on Windows 7?

Comment: It doesn't work. I did:
- install the kb3140245 update
- update the registry to activate TLS using EasyFix. I check the results and everything  in the registry seems to be "TLS compliant"
- add a key to the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client
DWORD name: DisabledByDefault
DWORD value: 0
- reboot the computer.
Same error, same issue.

I tried to apply what is mentionned here https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client but the .NET updates process are cryptic